# How To Run Controller Functionality Again Using Different Parameters From View ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have a controller that works fine on initial load. It calls user [0] data and everything processes fine. When I change dropdown, I want to call the same function, but I cannot get the entire controller to reload. It starts from the function call and leaves undefined in places where it pulls correct information (linkToken, etc) on initial load. Is there a way I can get it to reload all data from the controller instead of just from the function?

After calling the testchange() from the view to pass in the new data, I get :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'locations' of undefined
at h.$scope.updateLocations (refillController.js:261)
at refillController.js:73

But, when I call the original getRefills() that is ran on the initial page load I get the same error. How can I define these so the load after the onchange(0)?

```
angular.module('FinalApp.Controllers').controller('refillController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $location, $modal, userService, dependentsService, accountService, sharedCollections, configurationService, refillsService) {

$scope.user = userService.GetUserInformation();
$scope.userInfoArr = [];
//$scope.tests.push({'Name':$scope.user.FirstName, 'LinkToken':$scope.user.LinkToken});
$scope.userInfoArr = $scope.user.Dependants.map(function(item){return {'Name':item.FirstName, 'LinkToken':item.LinkToken}});
$scope.userInfoArr.splice(0, 0, {'Name': $scope.user.FirstName, 'LinkToken': $scope.user.LinkToken});
console.log($scope.userInfoArr);
$scope.finUserInfoArr = $scope.userInfoArr[0].LinkToken;
$scope.billingInfo = null;
$rootScope.showNavbar = true;

$scope.selectedMethod = null;
$scope.location = null;
$scope.payment = null;

$scope.refills = [];
$scope.deliverTypes = [];
$scope.locations = [];
$scope.payments = [];
$scope.allSelected = false;
$scope.loadingBillingInfo = false;
$scope.isMailOrder = false;
    //Detect Mobile Switch Refill List To Grid
    if(window.innerWidth <= 800) {
        $scope.view = "Grid";
    } else {
        $scope.view = "List";
    }

$scope.changeViewToList = function () {
    $scope.view = "List";
};

$scope.changeViewToGrid = function () {
    $scope.view = "Grid";
};

$scope.testchange = function(selectedTest) {
    $scope.getRefills(selectedTest);


    console.log(selectedTest);

};

$scope.getRefills = function (linkToken) {
    $scope.allSelected = false;
    $scope.loading = true;

    refillsService.GetRefills(
        linkToken,
        $scope.selectedMethod,
        $scope.location,
        $scope.payment
    ).then(function (data) {
        $scope.refills = [];
        _.each(data.Prescriptions, function (item) {
            fillRefills(item);
        });
        fillDeliverTypes(data.DeliveryTypes);
        if (!$scope.selectedMethod)
            $scope.selectedMethod = data.DeliveryTypeId;

        if (!$scope.location)
            $scope.location = data.PickupLocationId;

        if (!$scope.payment)
            $scope.payment = data.PaymentTypeId;

        $scope.loading = false;

        $scope.updateLocations();
    })["catch"](function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        $scope.loading = false;
        alertify.alert(configurationService.ErrorMessage("getting your refills", error.Message));
    });
};



var fillRefills = function (item) {
   //TODO-CallDoc temp fix
    if (item.RefillClass == "CALL_DOCTOR") {
        item.NextRefillDate = '1900-01-01T00:00:00'
    }
    var parsedDate = checkDate(moment(item.NextRefillDate).format('L'));
    var lastrefill = checkDate(moment(item.LastDispenseDate).format('L'));
    var expireDate = checkDate(moment(item.ExpirationDate).format('L'));
    var status = (item.RefillStatus.indexOf("After") == -1) ? item.RefillStatus : "Refill " + item.RefillStatus;
    $scope.refills.push({
        selected: false,
        rx: item.ScriptNo,
        name: item.DrugName,
        dose: item.UnitsPerDose,
        dir: item.Instructions,
        nextfill: parsedDate,
        lastfill: lastrefill,
        refillsLeft: item.NumRefillsLeft,
        status: status,
        msg: item.RefillMessage,
        canSelect: item.IsRefillable,
        refillClass: item.RefillClass,
        lastDispenseQty: item.LastDispenseQty,
        DaysSupply: item.DaysSupply,
        expireDate: expireDate,
        copayAmt: item.CopayAmt,
        drFirstName: item.DoctorFirstName,
        drLastName: item.DoctorLastName,
        writtenQty: item.WrittenQty
    });
};

var checkDate = function (date) {
    if (date == "01/01/1900") return "N/A";

    if (date == "Invalid Date") return "";
    return date;
};

var fillDeliverTypes = function (deliverTypes) {
    $scope.deliverTypes = [];
    _.each(deliverTypes, function (item) {
        $scope.deliverTypes.push({
            id: item.DeliveryTypeId,
            name: item.DeliveryTypeName,
            locations: item.PickupLocations,
            payments: item.PaymentTypes
        });
    });
};


var getBillingInfo = function () {
    $scope.loadingBillingInfo = true;
    accountService.GetCreditCardInfo().then(function (data) {
        $scope.billingInfo = data;
        $scope.loadingBillingInfo = false;
    })["catch"](function (error) {
        $scope.loadingBillingInfo = false;
        alertify.alert(configurationService.ErrorMessage("getting account information", error.Message));
    });
};

var getAccountInfo = function () {
    accountService.GetAccountInfo().then(function (data) {
        if (data.StatusCode == "SUCCESS") {
            $scope.user = data;
            userService.SaveUserInformation(data);
            if ($scope.user.IsLinked) {
                $rootScope.enableMyRefills = true;
                $rootScope.enableMyReports = true;
                window.location.hash = "#/refills";
            } else {
                $rootScope.enableMyRefills = false;
                $rootScope.enableMyReports = true;
            }
        } else {
            alertify.alert(configurationService.ErrorMessage("getting account information", data.StatusMessage));
        }
    })["catch"](function (error) {
        alertify.alert(configurationService.ErrorMessage("getting account information", error.Message));
    });
};


var openModal = function (viewUrl, controllerUrl, size, payload) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: viewUrl,
        controller: controllerUrl,
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            data: function () {
                return payload;
            }
        }
    });
    return modalInstance;
};

$scope.toggleRxSelection = function(rx) {
    if (rx.canSelect) {
        rx.selected = !rx.selected;
        $scope.evaluateAllSelected();
    }
};

$scope.selectAll = function (data) {
//        $scope.allSelected = allSelected;
    _.each($scope.refills, function (x) {
        if (x.canSelect) x.selected = data;
    });
};

$scope.evaluateAllSelected = function () {
    var count = _.countBy(_.where($scope.refills, {canSelect:true}), function(refill) {
       return refill.selected ? 'selected' : 'not';
    });

    $scope.allSelected = (count.not === undefined);
};

$scope.openEditCreditCardInfo = function () {
    var payload = ($scope.billingInfo != null && $scope.billingInfo != undefined)
    && $scope.billingInfo.CardNumber != "" ? $scope.billingInfo : {};

    if (payload != {}) {
        payload.ExpMonth = {id: parseInt(payload.ExpMonth)};
        payload.ExpYear = {id: parseInt(payload.ExpYear)};
    }

    openModal('app/views/editAccount/billingInformation.html', "billingInformationController", "xlg", payload).result.then(function () {
        getAccountInfo();
        getBillingInfo();
    }, function () {
        getBillingInfo();
    });
};

$scope.openConfirmOrder = function () {
    var refillsSelected = _.where($scope.refills, {selected: true});
    var location = _.findWhere($scope.locations, {PickupLocationId: $scope.location});
    var payment = _.findWhere($scope.payments, {PaymentTypeId: $scope.payment});
    var deliver = _.findWhere($scope.deliverTypes, {id: $scope.selectedMethod});
    if (refillsSelected.length == 0) {
        alertify.error("You need to select at least one refill");
        return;
    }

    if (deliver.id == 10001 && !$scope.user.IsCreditCardOnFile) {
        alertify.error("Need credit card on file for mail order");
        return;
    }

    sharedCollections.setRefills(refillsSelected);
    sharedCollections.setLocation(location);
    sharedCollections.setPayment(payment);
    sharedCollections.setDeliver(deliver);
    openModal('app/views/refills/confirmOrder.html', "confirmOrderController", "xlg").result.then(function () {
        $scope.billingInfo = accountService.GetCreditCardInfo();
        $scope.getRefills();
    }, function () {
        //$scope.billingInfo = accountService.GetCreditCardInfo();
        //getRefills();
    });

};

$scope.showRefill = function (rx) {
    var data = {rx: rx, refills: $scope.refills};
    openModal('app/views/refills/showRefills.html', "refillsCarrousel", "xlg", data).result.then(function () {
        $scope.evaluateAllSelected();
    }, function () {
        $scope.evaluateAllSelected();
    });
};


$scope.updateLocations = function () {
    $scope.locations = _.findWhere($scope.deliverTypes, {id: $scope.selectedMethod}).locations;
    $scope.payments = _.findWhere($scope.deliverTypes, {id: $scope.selectedMethod}).payments;
    setLocationAndPayment();

};

var setLocationAndPayment = function () {
    if ($scope.locations.length == 1) {
        $scope.location = $scope.locations[0].PickupLocationId;
    }

    if ($scope.payments.length == 1) {
        $scope.payment = $scope.payments[0].PaymentTypeId;
    }
    //check for mail order
    ($scope.selectedMethod == 10001 && !$scope.payment) ? $scope.isMailOrder = true : $scope.isMailOrder = false;
};


$scope.getRefills($scope.finUserInfoArr);
getBillingInfo();
```

});

Comment: the logic here is all wrong.  all these properties should be part of an object, not properties of the controller.

Comment: Can you explain to me why it works on initial page load but fails after? So these properties should be on the $scope.getRefills object? Sorry, still learning angular.

Comment: sorry to say but this code is a structural nightmare. 80% of it belongs in services

Comment: to be quite honest, after reading the first 100 or so lines of code posted here, it became obvious that it would probably take less time to rewrite it than figure out why it is broken, if one had knowledge of the problem domain.

Comment: Looks like I might have to go that route. This is a project that I'm taking over, so I'm having to extend from someone else' code.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `refillsService` returns correct data, it could be that `$scope.refills` remains empty array.